# how to access ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc to meet the error 'OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1'

Tags: cassandra, cql

In Cassandra 2.2.4 (cql 5.0.1):

I got an error `OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1.`

How can i access the `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` to set the value `client_timeout = 20`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to increase timeouts in your cassandra.yaml or allowing client to wait longer wont make a difference. The default read timeout is 5s, write 2s. The cqlsh default 10s exceeds that already so your timeout is probably from the coordinator (unless coordinator is hosed). That said just add a

```
[connection]
client_timeout = 20
```

in your ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc file.

Should probably try to address the slowness in your request as well, either your C* node is under distress or your query has issues. A timeout shouldn't happen in normal uses.